# CorePlot's Scatter plot not drawn with El Capitan 10.11 GM

Tags: objective-c, macos, core-plot

I have upgraded to 10.11 El Capitan and to Xcode 7, but it looks like the scatter plot line for my chart is not shown. Apparently the plot data source methods are not called. It works well under 10.10.X and I have made no change to the code whatsoever

```
#import "TempOutdoorViewController.h"
#import <CorePlot/CorePlot.h>
#import <Quartz/Quartz.h>

@interface TempOutdoorViewController ()


@end

@implementation TempOutdoorViewController

@synthesize plotData, data, metric, window;


- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect {
    // set any NSColor for filling, say white:
    [[NSColor clearColor] setFill];
    NSRectFill(dirtyRect);
}


-(void)awakeFromNib
{
     [super awakeFromNib];
    window.alphaValue = 0.0f;
    [window setBackgroundColor:[NSColor clearColor]];
    [window setOpaque:NO];

    NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];


    NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:(NSCalendarUnitYear | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute | NSCalendarUnitSecond) fromDate:now];
    [components setHour:0];
    [components setMinute:0];
    [components setSecond:0];
    NSDate *morningStart = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];

    NSTimeInterval todaysDiff = [morningStart timeIntervalSinceNow];


    NSDate *refDate       = morningStart;
    NSTimeInterval oneDay = -todaysDiff/[plotData count];


    // If you make sure your dates are calculated at noon, you shouldn't have to
    // worry about daylight savings. If you use midnight, you will have to adjust
    // for daylight savings time.
    NSMutableArray *newData = [NSMutableArray array];
    NSUInteger i;
    for ( i = 0; i < (unsigned long)[[data objectForKey:@"body"] count]; i++ ) {

        NSNumberFormatter *f = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];

        NSLocale *US = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"];

        [f setLocale:US];
        [f setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterNoStyle];        NSString *string =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[[[[data objectForKey:@"body"] objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"value"] objectAtIndex:0] objectAtIndex:0]];


        NSNumber *num;

        if ([metric isEqualToString:@"No"]) {
            num= [NSNumber numberWithDouble:([[f numberFromString:string] doubleValue] * 1.8 + 32)];

            ;
        }
        else{
            num=[f numberFromString:string];

        }


        if (num) {
            [array addObject:num];

        }
        else{

        }


        NSTimeInterval x = oneDay * i;
        id y             = num;
        //[NSDecimalNumber numberWithFloat:1.2 * rand() / (float)RAND_MAX + 1.2];
        [newData addObject:
         [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
          [NSDecimalNumber numberWithFloat:x], [NSNumber numberWithInt:CPTScatterPlotFieldX],
          y, [NSNumber numberWithInt:CPTScatterPlotFieldY],
          nil]];
    }



    // Create graph from theme
    graph = [(CPTXYGraph *)[CPTXYGraph alloc] initWithFrame : CGRectZero];
    CPTTheme *theme = [CPTTheme themeNamed:kCPTPlainWhiteTheme];
    [graph applyTheme:theme];
    hostView.hostedGraph = graph;
    graph.plotAreaFrame.paddingBottom = 25.0;
    graph.plotAreaFrame.paddingTop = 10.0;
    graph.plotAreaFrame.paddingLeft = 35.0;
    graph.plotAreaFrame.paddingRight = 25.0;
    graph.plotAreaFrame.borderLineStyle = nil;    // don't draw a border

    graph.plotAreaFrame.fill = [CPTFill fillWithColor:[CPTColor clearColor]];
    graph.fill = [CPTFill fillWithColor:[CPTColor clearColor]];
    //graph.backgroundColor = [NSColor clearColor];
    // Setup scatter plot space
    CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *)graph.defaultPlotSpace;
    NSTimeInterval xLow       = 0;
    plotSpace.xRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(xLow) length:CPTDecimalFromFloat(86400)];


    double interval;
    double mini;
    double mini2;

    if ([metric isEqualToString:@"No"]) {
        interval = ([[plotData valueForKeyPath:@"@max.self"] doubleValue]* 1.8  - [[plotData valueForKeyPath:@"@min.self"] doubleValue] * 1.8  )  ;
        mini = ([[plotData valueForKeyPath:@"@min.self"] doubleValue] )  * 1.8 + 32 ;

        mini2 = ([[plotData valueForKeyPath:@"@min.self"] doubleValue] )  * 1.8 + 32;



    }

    else {
        interval = ([[plotData valueForKeyPath:@"@max.self"] doubleValue] - [[plotData valueForKeyPath:@"@min.self"] doubleValue]+3);
        mini = [[plotData valueForKeyPath:@"@min.self"] doubleValue] -  1;

        mini2 = [[plotData valueForKeyPath:@"@min.self"] doubleValue] -1;

    }

    plotSpace.yRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromDouble(mini) length:CPTDecimalFromDouble(interval)];
    // Axes
    CPTXYAxisSet *axisSet = (CPTXYAxisSet *)graph.axisSet;

    CPTXYAxis *x          = axisSet.xAxis;
    x.majorIntervalLength         = CPTDecimalFromFloat(86400/4);
    x.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal = CPTDecimalFromDouble(mini2);
    x.minorTicksPerInterval       = 0;


    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    //  dateFormatter.dateStyle = kCFDateFormatterShortStyle;
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"h:mm a"];

    CPTTimeFormatter *timeFormatter = [[CPTTimeFormatter alloc] initWithDateFormatter:dateFormatter];
    timeFormatter.referenceDate = refDate;
    x.labelFormatter            = timeFormatter;
   // x.labelRotation = M_PI/4;

    CPTMutableTextStyle *axisTitleStyle = [CPTMutableTextStyle textStyle];

    NSString *osxMode = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"AppleInterfaceStyle"];

    if ([osxMode isEqualToString:@"Dark"]) {
        axisTitleStyle.color = [CPTColor whiteColor];

    }
    else {
    axisTitleStyle.color = [CPTColor blackColor];
    }
    axisTitleStyle.fontName = @"Helvetica-Bold";
    axisTitleStyle.fontSize = 10.0f;

    x.labelTextStyle = axisTitleStyle;
    NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [numberFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
    [numberFormatter setMaximumFractionDigits:0];
    CPTMutableLineStyle *majorGridLineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
    majorGridLineStyle.lineWidth = 0.75;

    if ([osxMode isEqualToString:@"Dark"]) {
        majorGridLineStyle.lineColor = [CPTColor colorWithComponentRed:255.0f/255.0f green:255.0f/255.0f blue:255.0f/ 255.0f alpha:1.0f];

    }
    else {
        majorGridLineStyle.lineColor = [[CPTColor colorWithGenericGray:0.2] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.75];
    }

    x.majorGridLineStyle = majorGridLineStyle;


    CPTXYAxis *y = axisSet.yAxis;

    if ([metric isEqualToString:@"No"]) {
        y.majorIntervalLength         = CPTDecimalFromString(@"5");
        numberFormatter.positiveSuffix =@"℉";

    }
    else{
        y.majorIntervalLength         = CPTDecimalFromString(@"2");
        numberFormatter.positiveSuffix =@"℃";

    }

    y.minorTicksPerInterval       = 0;
    y.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal = CPTDecimalFromDouble(0);
    y.labelFormatter = numberFormatter;
    y.labelTextStyle = axisTitleStyle;
    y.majorGridLineStyle = majorGridLineStyle;

    // Create a plot that uses the data source method
    CPTScatterPlot *dataSourceLinePlot = [[CPTScatterPlot alloc] init];
    dataSourceLinePlot.identifier = @"Date Plot";

    CPTMutableLineStyle *lineStyle = [dataSourceLinePlot.dataLineStyle mutableCopy];
    lineStyle.lineWidth              = 2.f;
    lineStyle.lineColor              = [CPTColor colorWithComponentRed:98.0f/255.0f green:147.0f/255.0f blue:202.0f/ 255.0f alpha:1.0f];
    dataSourceLinePlot.dataLineStyle = lineStyle;

    dataSourceLinePlot.dataSource = self;
    [graph addPlot:dataSourceLinePlot];








    NSLog(@"%@", newData);
    plotData = newData;

}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Plot Data Source Methods

-(NSUInteger)numberOfRecordsForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot
{
    return plotData.count;
}

-(NSNumber *)numberForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot field:(NSUInteger)fieldEnum recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
    NSDecimalNumber *num = [[plotData objectAtIndex:index] objectForKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:(int)fieldEnum]];

    return num;
}
```

Comment: For better drawing performance, set fills and line styles to `nil` if you don't need them rather than using a clear color.

Comment: Does the rest of the graph draw correctly and it's just the plot line missing?

Comment: Yes the rest of the graph (x and y axis, grid lines and labels are drawn). ( El Capitan 10.11) http://cl.ly/image/2x1t230s3k1r  (Yosemite 10.10) http://cl.ly/image/3Z2d06092b3H

Comment: The plot `dataSource` property holds a weak reference. Is there any way the view controller is being deallocated?

Comment: By disabling ARC for the AppDelegate that was creating the view controller  in the Compile Sources inside the Build Phases Tab with -fno-objc-arc I managed to get the scatter plot to be drawn. The view controller is inside a NSMenuItem, I don't really know how NSMenuItems are deallocated.